# Why reference to a local variable is still valid

Tags: c++

I am running following simple program in C++ program:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 string& ShowString()
 {
     string s1 = "abcd";
     return s1;
 }
 int main()
 {
     string s2 = ShowString();
     cout << s2 << endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

and the output is: `abcd`

The problem is that function `ShowString` returns a reference to a local variable and by the time that program reaches to `cout << s2 << endl`, `s1` should have been destroyed (and also `s2`). But the output is still correct, which brings me to the conclusion that although `s1` no longer exists, its contents in stack memory are still valid (probably until something else overwrites it).

I appreciate if you could let me know whether this conclusion is correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because it is an Undefined Behaviour. You can't trust that value.